# Prestashop 1.5.3 layered block filters based on atribute stock

Tags: prestashop

Im making a a new shop based on prestashop. But im facing a problem.

We sell shoes and such. They all have sizes so the total "stock" is based on sizes. EX: 1 x 36  1 x 37 etc.

So for example I have 10 shoe models with each 5 sizes if some of the sizes are sold out the layerd block still counts the product as in stock.

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check on your product Quantities on the Quantity tab on the product. If you have multiple combinations you need to manually check on it update.